# Sql commands Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, command

I'm trying to display the employeeno#, employee name, department, and salary for all employees who earn more than the average salary in their own department.

I've only tried this:

```
Select empno, ename, deptno,sal As Salary  
From emp  
Where sal >(SELECT AVG (sal) FROM emp);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this structure, you can use a correlation condition.  And that requires introducing table aliases:

```
select e.empno, e.ename, e.deptno, e.sal As Salary  
from emp e
where e.sal > (select avg(e2.sal) from emp e2 where e2.deptno = e.deptno);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to join the table to the average salaries of each `deptno` under the condition that the salary of the employee is more than the average:

```
select e.empno, e.ename, e.deptno, e.sal   
from emp e inner join ( 
  select deptno, avg(sal) sal from emp group by deptno
) t
on t.deptno = e.deptno and t.sal < e.sal
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle Database the most efficient query would be using analytic functions:

```
select empno, ename, deptno, sal from 
   (select emp.*, AVG(sal) over (partition by deptno) avgsal from emp) 
where sal > avgsal;
```

Just one table scan and filtering on the view.